# How to add custom attributes to a specific category in Magento

Tags: magento2, attributes

I need to add some custom attributes to a category in Magento. I only want to use for a special category, not all. Thanks
Such as attribute1, attribute2, which will belong tab "Custom Tab",  but I want to it only apply for Sport/Swimrun category,  not all categories, as image [link](https://prnt.sc/gizdun)

Comment: can you please explain more i will help you :)

Comment: @RamaChandraanMR ,  I want to add some custom attributes, which will belong tab "Custom Tab",  but I want to it only apply for Sport/Swimrun category,  not all categories, as image [link](https://prnt.sc/gizdun)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by creating a custom module and adding in a new category attribute.

You can find a tutorial here:
https://www.atwix.com/magento/add-category-attribute/

Comment: I want to add some custom attributes, which will belong tab "Custom Tab",  but I want to it only apply for Sport/Swimrun category,  not all categories, as image [link](https://prnt.sc/gizdun)